# Operação com horas Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Estava manipulando horas no Delphi e me deparei com a seguinte situação:

CASO 1

```pascal
horafinal := strtotime('08:00');
horaInicial := strtotime('17:00');

horaInicial := horaInicial - horafinal; //09:00
horafinal := horafinal - horafinal; //00:00

diferenca := horafinal - horaIncial; // 09:00
```

CASO 2

```pascal
horafinal := strtotime('08:00');
horaInicial := strtotime('17:00');

horaInicial := horaInicial - horafinal; //09:00
horafinal := strtotime('23:59') + strtotime('00:01'); //00:00

diferenca := horafinal - horaIncial; // 15:00
```

CASO 3

```pascal
horafinal := strtotime('08:00');
horaInicial := strtotime('17:00');

horaInicial := horaInicial - horafinal; //09:00
horafinal := strtotime('00:00'); //00:00

diferenca := horafinal - horaIncial; // 15:00
```

No meu entendimento isso ocorre, pois internamente ele deve utilizar um datetime. 
Caso 1  horafinal = hoje 00:00 e no Caso 2 Amanhã 00:00 e Caso 3 horafinal = Amanhã 00:00

Esse pensamento está correto? Como o Delphi trabalha com horas? Porque no caso 3 o delphi se comporta igual ao Caso 2 e não igual ao caso 1?

Comment: Não entendi qual o problema?

Comment: O delphi que você está usando possui a unit dateutils ? Existem funções lá que facilitam, e muito, o tratamento de datas.

Comment: @user3435518 hehe Sim, e estou usando no meu projeto. Só fui corrigir um bug e verifiquei esse comportamento e fiquei curiosa.

Comment: O que vocÊ tem que ver é que no Delphi (Ou FreePascal) as datas são armazenadas como um tipo double, onde o que está a esquerda do ponto flutuante é tratato como data e o que está a direita é tratado como hora. A codificação específica utilizada para fazer isso gera uma série de artefatos que são um compromisso entre o que é mais exato e o que é mais eficiente no computador. Provavelmente você esbarrou num desses "artefatos".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bem, nos três casos você usou uma variável `horaInicial` e depois `horaIncial`. Vou assumir que o `i` faltando é um erro de digitação bobo apenas e não uma variável diferente.

Veja [nesta página](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=StrToTime) estes detalhes:

> The date is set to 30 dec 1899, one day short of the 19th century.
>
> **Warning** : the date value is set to 1 day short of the end of the 19th century. Exactly why is unclear.

Traduzindo para o português:

> A data é definida para 30 dez 1899, um dia antes do fim do século 19.
>
> **Cuidado** : o valor da data é definido para um dia antes do fim do século 19. Não é claro o porquê.

Veja [esta outra](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TDateTime):

> It appears that the reason for Delphi starting at 30 Dec 1899 is to make it as compatible as possible with Excel while at the same time not adopting Excel's incorrectness about dates.
>
> Because TDateTime is actually a double, you can perform calculations on it as if it were a number. This is useful for calculations such as the difference between two dates.

Traduzindo para o português:

> Parece que o motivo para o Delphi começar no dia 30 Dez 1899 é fazer ele ser o mais compatível possível com o Excel sem no entanto adotar a incorretude do Excel acerca de datas.
>
> Uma vez que o TDateTime é na verdade um double, você pode realizar cálculos nele como se fosse um número. Isto é útil para cálculos tais como diferenças entre duas datas.

Ou seja, um `TDateTime` é um double aonde a parte inteira é um número de dias desde 30/12/1899 e a parte fracionária são frações de dias (horas, minutos, segundos, etc).

Vamos substituir suas variáveis por `a`, `b`, `c` e `d` para entender o que se passa e rastrear o valor dos `double`s:

No seu caso 1, [como a pergunta estava originalmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/53387/1):

```pascal
a := strtotime('08:00'); // Valor double: 8/24
b := strtotime('17:00'); // Valor double: 17/24

c := a - a; // 00:00 // Zero
d := b - c; // 09:00 // 17/24 - 0 = 17/24. Definitivamente não é 09:00!

diferenca := c - d; // -17/24, ou seja, 17 horas antes da meia-noite do dia 30/12/1899, portanto 09:00 do dia 29/12/1899.
```

No caso 1, como a pergunta está agora:

```pascal
a := strtotime('08:00'); // Valor double: 8/24
b := strtotime('17:00'); // Valor double: 17/24

c := b - a; // 09:00 // 17/24 - 8/24 = 9/24
d := a - a; // 00:00

diferenca := d - c; // -9/24, ou seja, 9 horas antes da meia-noite do dia 30/12/1899, portanto 15:00 do dia 29/12/1899.
```

No caso 2:

```pascal
a := strtotime('08:00'); // Valor double: 8/24
b := strtotime('17:00'); // Valor double: 17/24

c := b - a; // 09:00 // 17/24 - 8/24 = 9/24
d := strtotime('23:59') + strtotime('00:01'); // 00:00 // Mas no dia 31/12/1899. Valor double: 1.

diferenca := d - c; // 15:00 // Isso dá (1 - 9/24) = 15/24, ou seja, 15:00 do dia 30/12/1899.
```

No caso 3:

```pascal
a := strtotime('08:00'); // Valor double: 8/24
b := strtotime('17:00'); // Valor double: 17/24

c := b - a; // 09:00 // 17/24 - 8/24 = 9/24
d := strtotime('00:00'); // 00:00

diferenca := d - c; // 15:00 // Isso dá (0 - 9/24) = -9/24, ou seja, 9 horas antes da meia-noite do dia 30/12/1899, portanto 15:00 do dia 29/12/1899.
```

---

**Conclusão:** Do jeito que a pergunta está agora, os 3 casos dão como resposta 15:00. No entanto no caso 1 da pergunta como era originalmente, o resultado era 09:00 porque você estava fazendo operações de uma forma diferente.

Comment: Desculpa, Quando verifiquei os valores realmente estavam errados, pois a ordem estava diferente do meu código original.

Comment: @PriscilaAlmeida Você mexeu bastante na pergunta. Calma aí que já atualizo a resposta.

Comment: @PriscilaAlmeida Resposta atualizada. :)

Comment: @PriscilaAlmeida Resposta atualizada novamente. :)